# How add a style on json error?

Tags: jquery, json, validation

I have the following code which add a span on a json error:

```
 if (json['error']['firstname']) {
  $('#shipping-address      input[name=\'firstname\']')
 .after('<span class="error">' +    json['error']['firstname'] + '</span>');
```

1) But how add a class to the input field and to the **Firstname** (example: color:red;) 
   if there is an json error and

2) then remove both (style classes and span class) if the field is filled in ?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the class to input like this:

```
if (json['error']['firstname']) {
    var $input = $('#shipping-address input[name="firstname"]');
    $input.addClass('someClass').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['firstname'] + '</span>');
}
```

then remove both (style classes and span class) if the field is filled in

```
$('input[name="firstname"]').keypress(function (event) {
    if (this.value !== '') {
        $(this).removeClass('someClass');
        $(this).next('span.error').removeClass('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried also a simplier thing which is also not working: `$('input').on('focusout',function(){
   $(this).removeClass('ClassError for input field');
});`

Comment: 1) Your code removes the error class of the span, but the span is still remaining (obviously). 2) It removes also ALL the error classes of the other spans. Sorry for asking, man.

Comment: The last line of your code only removes the class of the span. I've modified it into `$(this).next('span').remove();` and now it's working. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the element like this before appending it to the desired element.

```
var span = $('<span></span>', {
    "class" : "yourClass",
    "style" : {
        "background" : "red"
    },
    "html"  : json['error']['firstname']      
});
```

If you want to add a class and a span on error, it should look something like this:

```
 if (json['error']['firstname']) {
     $('input[name="yourName"]').addClass('error');
     span.appendTo('input[name="yourName"]');
 }
```

Finally, create a listener for the input onchange to detect a valid value and remove class and span:

```
$('input[name="yourName"]').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $(this).removeClass('error');
        $(this).find('span').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: my code's working, but I want to add a class to the input field and to the bold element FIRSTNAME if there is an error, and then remove both if the field is filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (json['error']['firstname']) 
{
  $('#shipping-address input[name=\'firstname\']').after('<span class="error">' +    json['error']['firstname'] + '</span>');
$('#shipping-address input[name=\'firstname\']').addClass('error_new');
}
```

Comment: but how to remove both if the field is filled in?